# Unable to delete file android studio 3.1.3

Tags: android

I'm new here and I need your help to solve this problem :

[image]

Comment: You might want to add more information to your post.

Answer (score 0):

clean your project cache, execute cmd :

```
gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

Comment: Tank you Jie Xu for your answer. I try the cmd but I have also the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

You need to go to the source file directly. Close the studio and go to the path the issue is located at and delete the folder there.